# $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x \geq 0, x^Ty \leq 1 ~~\forall y \text{ and } \|y\| = 1\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x \geq 0, x^Ty \leq 1 ~~\forall y \text{ and } \|y \| = 1\}$ I need to show whether S is a polyhedral. Apparently it is not as I can reduce to show that S is merely a quarter of a circle and S will have infinte extreme points hence S is not a polyhedral.

However, there is one step in the question that I cannot derive.
One of the step is to show $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x^Ty \leq 1 ~~\forall y \text{ and } \|y\| = 1\}  = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid \|x\| \leq 1\}$

Note that I did not insert in the constraint $x \geq 0$ for the above equation just yet.

I tried to use all knowledge on inner space and properties but cannot effectively deduce the equation and a further question is how do I extrapolate this equation to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Start with $x^Ty\le\|x\|\|y\|\le\|x\|$, so if $\|x\|\le 1$ it's in the set. Now for any $x$ with $x^Ty\le 1$ one can choose $y$ as...

Comment: @Rzu It should be  easy to restrict the ball $\|x\|\le 1$ to $x\ge 0$, isn't it?

Comment: @A.Γ. Hi I understood the first part of your statement, but I do not quite understand why you need to say one can choose $y$ as?

Comment: For most of the possible $y$, $x^{T}y\le1$ doesn't mean that $x$ must be within the unit circle.

Comment: Maybe accept A.Γ.'s answer?  His hint is correct. Oh, and this doesn't look like linear programming.

Comment: @Rzu It is under linear programming as polyhedron is one of the topics. But of course need to know some linear algebra

Comment: My bad, I thought it is just for optimization.

Comment: I remember some of my friends, who were math majors. Fun times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote
\begin{align}
S_1&=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x^Ty \leq 1 ~~\forall y \text{ and } \|y\| = 1\},\\
S_2  &= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid\|x\| \leq 1\}.
\end{align}

1. Cauchy-Schwarz $x^Ty\le\|x\|\|y\|\le\|x\|$ shows that $S_2\subset S_1$.
2. To prove $S_1\subset S_2$, take $x\in S_1$, i.e. $x^Ty\le 1$ for *all* $y$ i the unit ball. Can you pick one $y$ to make it sure that $\|x\|\le 1$?

> What about $y=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$? (If $x\ne 0$, of course.)

Comment: If i pick $y = \dfrac{x}{|x|}$, then $x^Ty = ||x|| \leq 1$. But I still do not understand that the $y$ you chose means for all $y$ on the unit ball

Comment: @ilovewt When you are proving $S_1\subset S_2$, you take some $x\in S_1$ and need to show that $x\in S_2$. This is done by taking $y$ as above. It is "two inclusings proof" of equaity of two sets. The case they are all $y$ is covered by another inclusion.

Comment: Hi this i understand, but however, we are taking any $x \in S_1$ and then show that this $x \in S_2$. So I am wondering that this any $x \in S_1$ must fulfill $x^Ty \leq 1$ and for $||y|| = 1$, hence do we need to check whether $x^Ty \leq  1 \implies ||x|| \leq 1$ for $y = (1,0)$ for example.

Comment: Yes, you take an arbitrary $x$ from $x^Ty\le 1$. Your point is to prove that this can happen only if $\|x\|\le 1$ and never otherwise. The proof: for this $x$ that satisfies $x^Ty\le 1$ for all $\|y\|\le 1$ one can test $y=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ (since it is for any $y$) and get $\frac{x^Tx}{\|x\|}=\|x\|\le 1$. Bingo! This $x$ must be in the other set. Note that it is only "one half proof" of the whole.

Answer (score 0):

I will just use a x-y Cartesian coordinate, instead of theorems in linear algebra.

$\lVert\vec{y}\rVert = 1$ means $y_1^2 + y_2^2 = 1$

$\vec{x}^{T}\vec{y}$ means dot product.

Dot product formula:

$\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} = \lVert \vec{x} \rVert \lVert \vec{y} \rVert \cos(\theta)$

Since $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} \le 1$ and $\lVert \vec{y} \rVert \le 1$, 
we have $\lVert \vec{x} \rVert \cos(\theta) \le 1$

So $\vec{x}$ is not necessarily within the unit circle for all possible $\vec{y}$. For example, for $\cos(\theta) = 0.1$, $\lVert \vec{x} \rVert$ can be 10.

Have to choose a specific $\vec{y}$ that guarantees $\lVert \vec{x} \rVert \le 1$

Since the problem's condition is for all $\lVert \vec{y} \rVert \le 1$, you can choose a $\vec{y}$ that makes $\theta$ have a specific value, which can force $\lVert \vec{x} \rVert \le 1$.

For each possible $\vec{x}$, I choose a $\vec{y}$ that has a length of 1 and is parallel to $\vec{x}$.

That makes $\cos(\theta) = 1$. Since $\lVert \vec{x} \rVert \cos(\theta) \le 1$, that means $\lVert \vec{x} \rVert \le 1$.

The dot product formula and Cauchy–Schwarz inequality both work in higher dimensions.

Comment: Wait, $\|x\|\cos\theta\le 1$ must hold for *any* angle $\theta$, not just for $\cos\theta=0.1$.

Comment: So the question is: what (fixed) $x$ satisfies $\|x\|\cos\theta\le 1$ for *all possible* angles $\theta$?

Comment: Erh I mean what y makes that works. not my question so I won't think too much. Low-tech proof.

Comment: The I suggest you fix it or delete, otherwise you may get unpleasant downvotes to your reputation.

Comment: $\|x\|$ cannot be $10$, since one can always take $\cos\theta=1$ where $$\|x\|\cos\theta=10\cdot 1\le 1$$ is not true.

Comment: for some y, ||x|| can be 10. I was trying to show that he has to choose a specific y to make it work. He was thinking x must be within the unit circle, in 2nd sentence of that question. So I try to fix that first.

Comment: As for down-votes, the c++ tag in stackoverflow is much more hostile than here. Anyone would down-vote, it is fun to watch. Here is friendly.

Comment: He would get this now.